# Does being able to cast a divine spell, as a spell, because of a class feature make your class a divine spellcasting class?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spellcasting

There are multiple elements to the question I really *want* to ask, right now, but it primarily boils down to resolving a question about this Arcane Discovery:

The text of the Arcane Discovery "Faith Magic" is as follows.

> Faith Magic (Magic Tactics Toolbox pg. 3): Select one spell granted by a domain belonging to the god you worship. This spell must be at least 2 levels lower than the highest-level wizard spell you can cast. When you first prepare your spells for the day, you can prepare this spell once, using a spell slot 1 level higher than the spell’s actual level. **This is cast as a divine spell.**

(emphasis mine.)

What does this mean, for the purpose of prerequisites involving divine spellcasting such as "able to cast Xth-level divine spells"?  Does this mean that such a character would have an arcane spellcasting class that was also a divine spellcasting class?

Comment: (Yes I am thinking about Mystic Theurge.)

Comment: Just put that this is for the purpose of qualifying for MT in your question. Comments are periodically purged

Comment: I'm aware, but the question is not About Mystic Theurge; it's about *anything with a divine spellcasting prerequisite.*  There's other things that care about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This satisfies some prereqs, but it's ambiguous for others.

#### "Divine spellcaster" isn't clearly defined.

The game doesn't clearly define a "divine spellcaster." The closest it comes to defining it is as part of the [divine spells section](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Divine%20Spells&Category=Magic%20Basics), which can't be taken as comprehensive at this point: there are multiple divine spellcasters that do not prepare spells like this. Prerequisites around spellcasting broadly fall into two buckets:

- Arcane/divine spellcaster, often coupled with a caster level requirement, e.g. [Arcane Blast](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Arcane%20Blast) or [Divine Interference](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Divine%20Interference).
- Able to cast arcane/divine spells of a certain level or at all, e.g. [Mystic Theurge](https://www.aonprd.com/PrestigeClassesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mystic%20Theurge) or [Divine Dignity](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Divine%20Dignity).

[Faith Magic](https://aonprd.com/WizardArcaneDiscoveries.aspx) is unique (as far as I know) in terms of granting the ability to cast a spell outside of your typical tradition (without it just being an SLA, which [doesn't satisfy most prereqs](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qow)). The definitions of an arcane/divine spellcaster are based on the classes themselves, which implies that it's an innate characteristic of the class (i.e., a wizard is just an arcane spellcaster). Ultimately the rules do not make it clear as to whether a wizard who can cast a single divine spell is both an arcane and a divine spellcaster or if they're simply an arcane spellcaster who has a divine spell. Some elements of the game such as [Divine Defiance](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Divine%20Defiance) reference "levels in a divine casting class" which lends credence to it being an inherent aspect of a class, but there's nothing concrete either way.

There are other aspects that reference being an arcane/divine spellcaster (such as [Divine Strategist](https://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Cleric%20Divine%20Strategist), an archetype; [Talisman of Pure Good](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicArtifactsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Talisman%20of%20Pure%20Good), an artifact; or [Atheist Abjurations](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Atheist%20Abjurations), a feat) which would be impacted by this ruling.

#### "Able to cast spells" is more clearly defined.

Divine Dignity, for example, requires the "ability to cast divine spells." Mystic Theurge requires that you are "able to cast 2nd-level divine spells" (note that "spells," in spite of being plural, does not actually requires the ability to cast multiple spells per [this official rules response](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pxt5&page=2?Qualifying-for-PrCs-using-spelllike-abilities#70)).

Faith Magic allows you cast a spell as a divine spell, so it unambiguously meets the criteria for Divine Dignity or Mystic Theurge (with the caveat that while it requires a higher-level slot to prepare it does not raise the level of the spell, so you would need to be a 7th level wizard). Whether it also allows you to use a Talisman of Pure Good is ambiguous.